Exponential Family with Complete Sufficient Statistic
Suppose that $X$ is in an exponential family taking values in $\sigma$-finite space $(\mathcal{X}, F_{\mathcal{X}}, \nu)$ probability density function $f_{\theta}(x)=h(x) \exp \{\eta(\theta)^T T(x)-\kappa(\eta(\theta))\}$. Here $h : \mathcal{X} \to [0, \infty)$, $\eta:\Theta \to \mathbb{R}^k$, and $T:\mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}^k$. All notions of completeness/sufficiency we will be talking about are for $\theta$. By Fisher-Neyman factorisation theorem, $T$ is a sufficient statistic . Known results show that if the family is full rank, then $T$ is complete .
How about the converse? Suppose that we are told that $T$ is complete, can we prove that the family is full rank or do we have an explicit counterexample?
My guess is that the converse is true. An outline is as follows :

By Bahadur's theorem, every finite dimensional (boundedly) complete sufficient statistic is minimal sufficient. Therefore, $T$ is minimal sufficient.
Since $T$ is minimal sufficient, for any $x,y \in \mathcal{X}$, we should have that $\frac{f_{\theta}(x)}{f_{\theta}(y)}$ does not depend on $\theta$ if and only if $T(x)=T(y)$.
Suppose for the sake of contradiction that the family is not full rank. Put $H = \eta(\Theta)$. In this case, $\frac{f_{\theta}(x)}{f_{\theta}(y)}$ does not depend on $\theta$ can happen if $T(x)-T(y) \in H^{\perp}$ and $T(x)-T(y) \neq 0$. But this has to do with the range of $T$. We would need to show that, if the range of $T$ misses some important dimensions, then it shall fail to be complete. (I cannot fill in the details of this step).

